# Can you call a function at the end of a keyframes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a game in HTML/JS/CSS and it has a sort of news system at the top where text scrolls across the screen, and once it reaches the end a new string of text starts scrolling. The way I have it generate a new string is by changing it every 20 seconds using setTimeout. Most of the time, this works well, but every now and then the keyframes animation and setTimeout get off sync (from browser notifs, switching tabs, switching windows, etc.). This causes the message to change halfway through the keyframes animation, and it stays off sync unless it happens to sync up later.

I've tried looking for ways to call JS functions at the end of a CSS keyframes animation, but I haven't found anything.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animationend_event

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One approach you could take is to synchronize the JavaScript timeout with the CSS animation

```js
function changeNewsText() {
  // Change the news text here
}

// Get the duration of the CSS animation
const animationDuration = 10; // 10s in this case, adjust as needed

// Set the timeout to fire just after the animation duration
setTimeout(function() {
  changeNewsText();
  // Call this function recursively to keep changing the news text
  setTimeout(arguments.callee, animationDuration * 1000);
}, animationDuration * 1000);
```

```css
#newsTicker {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

#newsText {
  position: absolute;
  animation: newsScroll 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes newsScroll {
  0% { transform: translateX(100%); }
  100% { transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
```

```html
<div id="newsTicker">
  <div id="newsText">This is the news text.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks basically the same as what I have, my current problem is that the timeout is paused during a browser notification or switching tabs while the animation is not.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).